# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

we have internet site on 2 servers with load balance server the code is identical on both servers but one of the servers shows the below exception every minut, the  "$MainContent$ASPCONTROL" is changing each time.

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$MainContent$drpOwnerNationality="...lect'"()&%<acx><ScRiPt >prompt...").   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection collection, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)_ApplicationError,
```

Comment: I think one of your control has script..ASP.Net does potential XSS validation of your all inputs on the form,...So it is detecting script like string in one of your controls that is what exceptions states..

Comment: please also add the asp.net page side code

Comment: are you sending HTML in any of the input fields to server ?

Answer (score 0):

I think one of your control (drpOwnerNationality) has script..ASP.Net does potential XSS validation of your all inputs on the form...So it is detecting script in one of your controls that is what exceptions states.

Problem could be one of user of your application is entering script in Textbox/Control and you are not validting at your client end.

One way is to do validation at client end and inform users that they cannot enter scripts in your control

other way is to turn off validation by setting validateReqeust attribute on page to false

```
<@ Page validateRequest="false" %>
```

But if you do this then you have exposed your application to XSS attacks.One way could be you disable the validation and do encoding of all your input before processing that information...

```
`HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode(drpOwnerNationality.SelectedText);` // assuming it is dropdown
```

Comment: drpOwnerNationality is dropdownlist and it shouldn't contain "...lect'"()&%<acx><ScRiPt >prompt...") also there is a client validation for textboxes but not for dropdownlist that have Name,Value binded from DB and the user have to choose from them

Comment: Yeah...did you check your DB was not having script text which you were binding to dropdown....Good idea would be to Encode text before binding it to Dropdown

Comment: we don't insert like this scripts to DB and we are not allowing to insert those scripts to DB however the problem is the w3wp process is consuming more memory on this server.

Comment: the other server have the same code and it didn't show any problems

Comment: It is not about the code but about the data in database...your code in other server is also vulnerable of the same issue....For some reason which you only can check, instances when database returned script data happened only one server...Did you check how many times you got the error? are you sure it is not happening at all at the other server? What was data which were tried to bind to dropdown? Can't you run the query and verify the data in database? Did you test with same input in both the server?

Comment: if you are sure dropdown values are plain text and does not have html or script tags then one more possibility is someone is using tool like fiddler which allows you to break into HTTP Post request  and update values in form collection.......definitely it is data problem....

Answer (score 0):

Error causes because you try to send pure html or other content which may contain unsecure elements.
1. You can disable request validation just like in following [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
2. Other option you may convert your content to Base64 before send using 3rd party JavaScript library (try google it).

There are several other options but it depends from your case.

Comment: I don't try to send unsecure HTML,  
drpOwnerNationality is dropdownlist and it shouldn't contain "...lect'"()&%<acx><ScRiPt >prompt...") also there is a client validation for textboxes but not for dropdownlist that have Name,Value binded from DB and the user have to choose from them

Answer (score 0):

we detected huge hits from 2 IPs, after blocking them the problem solve.
seems somebody was trying to post unsecure html

Answer (score 0):

validateRequest = false is not a good solution. We used this to overcome this issue:

On the server side, you can use this:

Create a hidden field in asp.net and encode it.

```
hiddenFieldMessage.Value = Uri.EscapeDataString(dangerousString);
```

Then in Javascript, create a text area and decode the encoded value.

```
<script>
    (function () {
        
        const content = document.getElementById('<%= hiddenFieldMessage.ClientID %>').value;
        // decode the content back to html
        var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textArea.innerHTML = decodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('<%= hiddenFieldMessage.ClientID %>').value);
        const content = textArea.value;  // decoded value
   })
```